# Constructor and Destructor of instances in c++ Polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have an example of me trying to create a derived class "Dog" from base class "Animal" but I want to create instances of Animal class and use its members (I'm fairly new to polymorphism in c++).
The result produces 2 lines of "An animal is created!" and 1 line of "A dog is created!" while I'm expecting 1 line of each.

```
class Animal
{

private:

    int numberOfLegs;
    const char* name;
public:

    int getNumberOfLegs();
    const char* getName();
    virtual void ToString()
    {
        std::cout << "This animal has " << this->getNumberOfLegs();
        std::cout << "leg and its name is " << getName() << std::endl;
    }
    Animal(int, const char*);
    ~Animal();
};

int Animal::getNumberOfLegs()
{

    return this->numberOfLegs;
}

const char* Animal::getName()
{

    return this->name;
}

Animal::Animal(int legs, const char* name)
{

    this->numberOfLegs = legs;
    this->name = name;
    std::cout << "An animal is created!" << std::endl;
}

Animal::~Animal()
{

    std::cout << "An animal is destroyed!" << std::endl;
}

class Dog : public Animal
{
private:

    const char* speech;
public:
    void ToString()
    {

        std::cout << "This dog has " << this->getNumberOfLegs();
        std::cout << " legs and its name is " << this->getName();
        std::cout << " and it says " << this->speech << std::endl;
    }

    Dog(int, const char*, const char*);

    ~Dog();
};

Dog::Dog(int legs, const char* name, const char* speech) : Animal (legs, name)
{

    this->speech = speech;
    std::cout << "A dog is created!" << std::endl;
}

Dog::~Dog()
{

    std::cout << "A dog is destroyed!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

        Animal anAnimal(3, "Godzilla");
        Dog myDoge(4, "CuteDoge", "woof");
        char c;
        std::cin.get(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: The rule of 3: you have a non-trivial destructor, so you need copy constructor and assignment operator. Also, the destructor in such a case must be virtual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your hierarchy, Dog inherits from Animal. This means that when a Dog is constructed Animal, its parent, is constructed first. That's why when you create a Dog you get both 'Animal is created' and 'Dog is created'.

To avoid other issues, you must follow the rule of 3: you have a non-trivial destructor, so you should also define copy constructor and assignment operator. Otherwise you will have a double-free and/or use freed memory.

Also, since you may have non-trivial children to Animal, you must make the destructor virtual. Otherwise,

```
std::unique_ptr<Animal> ptr = std::make_unique<Dog>();
```

without a virtual destructor in Animal, the Dog destructor will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

As `Dog` is an `Animal`, and in your constructor you might see:

```
Dog::Dog(int legs, const char* name, const char* speech) : Animal(legs, name)
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

calls base class constructor.

So

```
Dog myDoge(4, "CuteDoge", "woof");
```

would call both:

```
std::cout << "An animal is created!" << std::endl;
// ...
std::cout << "A dog is created!" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
Dog::Dog(int legs, const char* name, const char* speech) : Animal (legs, name)
```

Is the first line of the `Dog` [constructor](/questions/tagged/constructor) - objects must also construct all its Base classes ([base-class](/questions/tagged/base-class)) as part of construction - and here you are calling the Animal constructor with the arguments of `legs` and `name`